# How would you connect to two postgres databases in a sql script or a stored procedure?

Tags: postgresql, archive

I need to move some old data from one database to another - both have similar schemas. After the old rows in db1.mytable are inserted into db2.mytable - these same rows should be deleted from db1.mytable.

This is reduce db size and archive data that is not really needed that much but still important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should to use Foreign Data Wrapper for Postgres - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/postgres-fdw.html With foreign tables, you can send a query to another database.